# How to run the code between specific dates on QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtimer, qdatetime

How can I run the function I want in the code in the time interval I selected in the code I wrote in Qt? How can I set up a signal slot structure? can you show sample code?

for example in the code I want to run the function between 25.03.2022 and 04.03.2022.

can you show sample code?

Comment: I'm rather unclear as to exactly what you're trying to do.  Perhaps you could clarify?  If you want to run a function periodically look at [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtimer.html).  Regarding dates/times have a look at [`QDateTime`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdatetime.html).

Comment: Another, more robust approach may be to setup some events on the OS itself (f.ex. a crontab on unix). Otherwise, you should ensure that your program is actually running on the requested date (program crash, pc restart, ...).

Comment: I want certain function to run between selected dates in Qt interface.

Comment: Sorry, it is still unclear. Do you want to run the function once? Do you want to run it repeatedly? Or is it som kind of function with some cycle which should exit when the end date is reached? If you do not describe your problem precisely, you cannot get a good answer.

Comment: I want to run the function once and then repeatedly run owing to timer. Then, it is som kind of function with some cycle which should exit when the end date is reached.